# React Render Another Component that Matches Current Component

Tags: arrays, reactjs, onclick, render

I have a component Card.js that renders in a card format that comes from a data array. I want to achieve clicking on the card and then opening up another component called Suggestion.js, but I only want to open the results where the Card id matches the Suggestion id.  I've set up the handleClick function, but I'm having trouble coming up with the code to make work. I need help with code to change state of suggestion to match the suggestions where the id is the same in the card that is clicked.  Thanks!

App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import SignUp from './components/SignUp';
import NetworkArray from './components/NetworkArray';
import {network} from './NetworkData';
import {suggest} from './components/Suggest';
import './App.css';
import 'tachyons';
import Searchbox from './components/Searchbox';
import SignIn from './components/SignIn';
import Navigation from './components/Navigation';
import MyNetworkArray from './components/MyNetworkArray';
import SuggestArray from './components/SuggestArray';


class App extends Component  {

    constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
    network: network,
    suggest:suggest,
    searchfield:'',
    route:'signin'
}
this.handleChange=this.handleChange.bind(this);
this.handleClick=this.handleClick.bind(this);

}

onSearchChange=(event)=> {
  this.setState({searchfield:event.target.value})

}
handleClick(id)  {
                   //Code to render Suggestion.js to match id of Card Clicked
             }



handleChange(id) {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    const updatedNetwork = prevState.network.map(netw => {
      if (netw.id===id) {
        netw.isChecked = !netw.isChecked
      }
      return netw
    })
    return {
      network:updatedNetwork
    }
  })
}

onRouteChange=(route) => {
  this.setState({route:route})

}

render() {
  const filteredNetwork = this.state.network.filter(netw => {
    return netw.lastName.toLowerCase().includes(this.state.searchfield.toLowerCase())
  })

  return (
    <div className = "tc">
    <Navigation onRouteChange={this.onRouteChange} /> 
    {
    this.state.route==='home' ?
      <div> 
      <h2 className = "ml6">Members</h2> 
         <Searchbox searchChange = {this.onSearchChange}
          onRouteChange = {this.onRouteChange}
          /> 
         <NetworkArray 
             network={filteredNetwork}
             handleChange = {this.handleChange} 
             handleClick ={this.handleClick} 
             selectedCard={this.state.suggest}
             />
      </div> 
     : (
      this.state.route==='mynetwork' ? (
        <div>
         <h2 className = "ml6">My Network</h2>
         <Searchbox searchChange = {this.onSearchChange}
          onRouteChange = {this.onRouteChange} />
          <MyNetworkArray onRouteChange = {this.onRouteChange}
          handleChange = {this.handleChange}
          network = {filteredNetwork}/>
          </div>
       ) :  this.state.route === 'register' ?  (
          <SignUp onRouteChange = {this.onRouteChange} />
          ) :this.state.route ==='signin' ? (
          <SignIn onRouteChange = {this.onRouteChange}/>
          ) : this.state.route === 'suggestions' ? (
          <SuggestArray onRouteChange = {this.onRouteChange}
          suggest = {suggest}/>
          ) : (<SignIn /> )
    )

}

    </div>
  );
 }
}
export default App;
```

Card.js

```
import React from 'react';

const Card = (props,handleClick) => {

    return(
        <div className = 'pointer bg-light-green dib br3 pa3 ma2 grow  shadow-5'
        onClick = {() => props.handleClick(props.id)}>

        <div>
            <h3>{props.name}</h3>
            <p>{props.company}</p> 
            <p>{props.phone}</p>
            <p>{props.email}</p>
            <p>{props.city}</p> 

         </div>
         <div> 
            My Network
            <input className ="largeCheckbox"
                type = "checkbox"
                checked={props.isChecked}
                onChange={()=> props.handleChange(props.id)}
                    /> 
            </div> 
         </div> 

        )
}

export default Card;
```

SuggestArray.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Table from './Table';

const SuggestArray = ({suggest,handleChange}) => {
    const tableComponent = suggest.map((user,i) => {
        return(
        <Table 
            key = {suggest[i].id}
            location = {suggest[i].location} 
            restaurants = {suggest[i].restaurant}
            resdescription= {suggest[i].resdescription}
            attractions={suggest[i].attractions}
            attdescription = {suggest[i].attdescription}
            id={suggest[i].id}

            />

                    )
    })
        return ( 
                <div> 

                 {tableComponent}


                </div> 
            )
}

export default SuggestArray;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further understanding of your question, I suggest you filter the suggestions in your state when you handle click.

```
handleClick(id)  {
  this.setState({
    suggest: suggest.filter(suggest => suggest.id === id)
  });
}
```

Comment: I added this:  handleClick(id)  {
 this.setState({clickedId:id,route:'suggestions'})
}  
Is this where I was to put this in App.js:
 <SuggestArray id={this.state.clickedId} onRouteChange = {this.onRouteChange}
          suggest = {suggest}/>
When i click on the card it still opens everything in the array and not just the one where the id matches...?

Comment: Can you post your `SuggestArray` component? Would help me a lot to see it!

Comment: I added the SuggestArray.  Thx!

Comment: Oh interesting. So multiple suggestions can be showed if multiple cards have been clicked?

Comment: No. I just want to render the suggestions of the one user.  I'm using another button to show everything.  I just want to see the suggestions of user that matches the card.

Comment: Okay, I have updated my answer, I hope this is closer to what you need!

Comment: Nick, So do I leave everything else suggested the same?   Because now when I click the card the SuggestArray opens but it's blank.

Comment: This is tough to troubleshoot because there's still quite a bit of opaqueness in what you've shared. I can't tell if `suggest` is a component or array of objects. Additionally, I'm not quite sure what the `Table` component does with everything you're passing to it

Comment: Awesome Nick. I just changed suggest={this.state.suggest} from suggest={suggest} and it started working.